# Topological Field - What does it mean for operations to be continuous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, field-theory

I understand the notion of a field $(\mathsf{F}, +, \times)$, of a topological space $(\mathsf{F}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{F})$ and of a continuous function $f:\mathsf{X}\to\mathsf{Y}$ between two topological spaces $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{X})$ and $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{Y})$. However I am struggling to understand the definition of a topological field.

> Let $(\mathsf{F}, +, \times)$ be a field and $(\mathsf{F}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{F})$ be a topological space. We say $(\mathsf{F}, \mathcal{T}_\mathsf{F}, +, \times)$ is a topological field if the operations of addition, multiplication, additive and multiplicative inverses are continuous.

#### Issue with the Cartesian Product

Let's take addition. By definition addition is a binary operation $+:\mathsf{F}\times\mathsf{F}\to\mathsf{F}$ satisfying some properties. For this to be continuous, it would have to be the case that $(\mathsf{F}\times\mathsf{F}, \mathcal{T}_{\mathsf{F}\times\mathsf{F}})$ is a topological space. However this doesn't seem to be the case in general? In particular, how is $\mathcal{T}_{\mathsf{F}\times\mathsf{F}}$ even defined?

Comment: Are you familiar with the **[product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology)**?

Comment: Open sets are unions of the form $\bigcup_{\alpha} U_\alpha \times V_\alpha$ where the factors are open in $\mathsf{F}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber actually I wasn't. Thank you for pointing it out. Do you know if in this case one should use the product topology or the box topology?

Comment: @Euler_Salter They're only different if *infinitely many* spaces are involved, which isn't the case here. (And when there are, you almost always want the product topology.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

There is in fact a canonical way to take the product of two topological spaces: if $\mathcal{X}=(X,\sigma),\mathcal{Y}=(Y,\tau)$ are topological spaces, their product $\mathcal{Z}=(Z,\rho)$ is given by $$Z=X\times Y,\quad\rho=\langle\sigma\times\tau\rangle.$$ Here the "$\langle...\rangle$" means "topology *generated by*." The set $\sigma\times\tau$ isn't actually a topology on $X\times Y$, but merely a *basis for* a topology on $X\times Y$; a general open set in $\rho$ is a *union* of elements of $\sigma\times\tau$.

For exapmle, if $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, then $Z=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\sigma\times\tau$ is the set of "open rectangles" in the plane; $\rho$, then is everything you can build out of open rectangles, which gives us the usual topology on the plane.

---

We can also take the product of *more than two* spaces. Once infinitely many spaces are involved, however, a subtlety enters the picture: the naive guess at what the topology on an infinite product should be is too big! Given an infinite set of topological spaces $\mathcal{X}_i=(X_i,\sigma_i)$ ($i\in I$), the right topology on the product set $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is (usually) **not** the topology generated by $\prod_{i\in I}\sigma_i$. This is really a digression you shouldn't dive into until the two-spaces case is understood, but it is worth mentioning; the relevant terms are "**product topology**" and "**box topology**."